# Amchart - Last value always shown in right side of graph

Tags: amcharts

I am using Amchart. I have a requirement that last value could be displayed to right of chart and could be colour-coded as shown in attached picture.

Could you please some one help me how to achieve this.

[Amchart - Circled the last value shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4AZj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I got answer.

http://www.amcharts.com/tips/use-guides-to-display-value-of-the-last-data-point-on-value-axis/

Thank you Amchart.